# Примерная замена кубического Безье на две дуги

Tags: любой-язык, gd, кривые-безье

Привет. Мой старый графический фреймворк (GD) не умеет рисовать кубические кривые Безье (вообще никакие не умеет). С целью отрисовки символов из TTF шрифтов (напрямую задача не позволяет), хочу как-то частично неадекватно заменить кривые Безье на дуги. Но как? Мне не нужны готовые научные работы (я знаю, они есть и имеют промышленный смысл), которые позволяют набором дуг приблизить результат к кривой Безье максимально точно. Мне достаточно двух дуг.

Вот что у меня есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Координаты точек P₁ и P₂ известны. Координаты контрольных точек C₁ и C₂ тоже. Из точек P₁ и P₂ я провел прямые перпендикулярно отрезкам P₁C₁ и P₂C₂ красного цвета. Центры искомых дуг будут лежать на этих прямых, иначе касательные в точках P₁ и P₂ не совпадут, и нарушается условие задачи.

Дальше я решил действовать так. Через среднюю точку P₀ между точками P₁ и P₂ я провел перпендикулярную отрезку между ними прямую (серый цвет), далее "серый перпендикуляр". Потом добавляю первую окружность (зеленый цвет):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что в зависимости от ее радиуса R₁ ее центр просто "ездит" по красной прямой, при этом изменяется точка пересечения с серым перпендикуляром и угол пересечения.

Аналогично все и с второй окружностью радиуса R₂ (синий цвет):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, мне нужно найти такие значения радиусов R₁ и R₂, чтобы обе окружности пересекались с серым перпендикуляром в одной точке, кроме того, имели в этой точке одинаковый угол касательной. Дальше я уж на дуги их сам как-нибудь порежу.

То есть, исходные данные это P₁, P₂, C₁, C₂, координаты которых (x, y) известны. А найти надо R₁ и R₂ (радиусы окружностей, скалярные числа).

Я уже не в силах решать уравнения с X и Y по-отдельности, с кучей тригонометрии. Может, с помощью векторной алгебры это как-то попроще-изящнее решается?

К вопросу, а что я уже сделал сам. Я решил немного другую задачу, когда заранее известен радиус первой дуги.

```
<?php

$width = 600;
$height = 600;

function demo($im) {

    $x1 = 124;
    $y1 = 253;
    imagefilledarc($im, $x1, $y1, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0x000000, 0);
    imagestring($im, 2, $x1-30, $y1+10, "x1, y1", 0x000000);

    $x2 = 445;
    $y2 = 428;
    imagefilledarc($im, $x2, $y2, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0x000000, 0);
    imagestring($im, 2, $x2+0, $y2+10, "x2, y2", 0x000000);

    imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, 0x000000);

    $xc1 = $x1 + 50;
    $yc1 = $y1 - 200;
    imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $xc1, $yc1, 0x000000);
    imagefilledarc($im, $xc1, $yc1, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0x000000, 0);

    $xc2 = $x2 -5;
    $yc2 = $y2 -200;
    imageline($im, $x2, $y2, $xc2, $yc2, 0x000000);
    imagefilledarc($im, $xc2, $yc2, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0x000000, 0);

    $d1 = 10 * sqrt( pow($x1-$xc1, 2) + pow($y1-$yc1, 2) );
    $ac1 = atan2($yc1-$y1, $xc1-$x1);
    $ap1 = $ac1 + pi() / 2.;
    $xp1 = $x1 + $d1*cos($ap1);
    $yp1 = $y1 + $d1*sin($ap1);
    imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $xp1, $yp1, 0x808080);

    $d2 = 10 * sqrt( pow($x2-$xc2, 2) + pow($y2-$yc2, 2) );
    $ac2 = atan2($yc2-$y2, $xc2-$x2);
    $ap2 = $ac2 - pi() / 2.;
    $xp2 = $x2 + $d2*cos($ap2);
    $yp2 = $y2 + $d2*sin($ap2);
    imageline($im, $x2, $y2, $xp2, $yp2, 0x808080);


    /** Принудительно задается радиус первой (красной) дуги, что неправильно!!! */
    $r1 = 135;
    /** Из него вычисляется положение центра красной дуги, обозначен красной точкой. */
    $r1x = $x1 + $r1*cos($ap1);
    $r1y = $y1 + $r1*sin($ap1);
    imagefilledarc($im, $r1x, $r1y, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0xFF0000, 0);
    imagestring($im, 2, $r1x-40, $r1y-30, "r1x, r1y", 0x000000);

    /** Это результат решения уравнения для заданного радиуса красной дуги */
    $L = (
        2.*($r1x*$x2 + $r1y*$y2)
        - pow($x2, 2)
        - pow($y2, 2)
        - pow($r1x, 2)
        - pow($r1y, 2)
        + pow($r1, 2)
    ) / 2. / (
        cos($ap2)*($x2-$r1x)
        + sin($ap2)*($y2-$r1y)
        + $r1
    );

    $xl = $x2 + $L*cos($ap2);
    $yl = $y2 + $L*sin($ap2);

    imagefilledarc($im, $xl, $yl, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0x00FF00, 0);

    $aspl = atan2($r1y-$yl, $r1x-$xl);

    imagearc($im, $r1x, $r1y, 2*$r1, 2*$r1, rad2deg($ap1)+180, rad2deg($aspl), 0xFF0000);
    imagearc($im, $xl, $yl, 2*$L, 2*$L, rad2deg($aspl), rad2deg($ap2)-180, 0x0000FF);

}

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, 0xc0c0c0);

demo($im);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im, null, 9);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае первая дуга красная. Но это не то, что нужно. Мне нужно, чтобы между дугами был некий "паритет", а не чтобы радиус первой задавался принудительно.

**Собираюсь начать конкурс.** Поэтому, чтобы не вводить участников в заблуждение, сейчас изложу то, к каким выводам за прошедшее время пришел сам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получил формулу для радиуса окружности от координаты любой точки (Xz, Yz), через которую она должна проходить:

```
            (Xz-X₁)² + (Yz-Y₁)²
R₁ = 2 ---------------------------
         (Xz-X₁)Cosβ + (Yz-Y₁)Sinβ

            (Xz-X₂)² + (Yz-Y₂)²
R₂ = 2 ---------------------------
         (Xz-X₂)Cosγ + (Yz-Y₂)Sinγ
```

Дальше обозначаю углы (нет на картинке) между осью абсцисс и
1) красным перпендикуляром из точки P₁ -- β
2) красным перпендикуляром из точки P₂ -- γ
3) серым перпендикуляром из точки P₀ -- δ
(угол α я зарезервировал на всякий случай для наклона самой прямой P₁P₂, но оно не понадобилось).

Дальше добавляется условие равенства касательных окружностей в точке (Xz, Yz). Это просто значит, что (Xz, Yz), (Xr₁, Yr₁) и (Xr₂, Yr₂) лежат на одной прямой. Простая пропорция:

```
Xz - Xr₁   Xz - Xr₂
-------- = --------
Yz - Yr₁   Yz - Yr₂
```

Потом я выражаю координаты точек через углы и расстояния от других точек:

```
Xz = X₀ + ZCosδ
Yz = Y₀ + ZSinδ
Xr₁ = X₁ + R₁Cosβ 
Yr₁ = Y₁ + R₁Sinβ
Xr₂ = X₂ + R₂Cosγ
Yr₂ = Y₂ + R₂Sinγ
```

В итоге получается:

**СИСТЕМА УРАВНЕНИЙ С ТРЕМЯ НЕИЗВЕСТНЫМИ (R₁, R₂, Z):**

```
            (Xz-X₁)² + (Yz-Y₁)²
R₁ = 2 ---------------------------
         (Xz-X₁)Cosβ + (Yz-Y₁)Sinβ

            (Xz-X₂)² + (Yz-Y₂)²
R₂ = 2 ---------------------------
         (Xz-X₂)Cosγ + (Yz-Y₂)Sinγ

Xz - Xr₁   Xz - Xr₂
-------- = --------
Yz - Yr₁   Yz - Yr₂

Xz = X₀ + ZCosδ
Yz = Y₀ + ZSinδ
Xr₁ = X₁ + R₁Cosβ 
Yr₁ = Y₁ + R₁Sinβ
Xr₂ = X₂ + R₂Cosγ
Yr₂ = Y₂ + R₂Sinγ
```

При том, все эти синусы и косинусы - вообще константы, поскольку углы (их аргументы) заданы как константы.

Как только я эту систему ни крутил. Раскрывал скобки, использовал компьютерную алгебру (программа Maxima), в том числе для частичных результатов. Выходит, что **аналитического решения нет**. А численные методы не подходят, я ведь символы из шрифтов собирался дугами рисовать, представляете, какая скорость получится.

Поэтому объявляется конкурс. **Имеет значение только заголовок вопроса.** Дальше решаем как хотим, только аналитически. Принимать к сведению все глупости, изложенные мною в тексте - не обязательно и может быть вредно.

P.S. Меня, кроме прочего, интересует "паритет" на основе некоторого соотношения между дугами (радиусами). Сделать маленькую окружность с заданными радиусом и "нацепить" на нее вторую -- это уже сделано в тексте вопроса.

Вот, кстати, отрицательное значение R₂. Отрисовано на PHP GD на основе первых двух формул без всяких дополнительных условий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть никакого ограничения на то, как далеко от точки P₀ может пересекаться окружность с серым перпендикуляром - нет.

Вот, на всякий случай, кому нужно, кубическая кривая Безье по точкам P₁, P₂ и контрольным точкам C₁ и C₂, кому нужно, красным пунктиром:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Её не нужно аппроксимировать, а просто нужно заменить чем-то гладким на основе двух дуг.

Добавлю анимацию в вопрос, а то что-то мало к нему внимания.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$r2 = .5 * (pow($r1, 2.) - pow($x2-$r1x, 2.) - pow($y2-$r1y, 2.)) /
    (cos($ap2)*($x2-$r1x) + sin($ap2)*($y2-$r1y) + $r1);
```

Где $ap2 - просто перпендикуляр к касательной в точке P2.

Comment: Я почти ничего не понял, но это офигеть как круто.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сперва я собирался сделать это за 10 минут, потом за 2 часа, потом подумал: не будет ничего страшного, если поморокую денёк над школьной геометрией, график свободный же. Потом оказалось, что решения просто нет.

Comment: А что такое P1/2 и C1/2?

Comment: @VladD это точки, по которым строится кривая Безье (которая мне на самом деле и не нужна вовсе). Кривая проходит через точки P1 и P2 по касательным, которые задаются задаются точками C1 и C2. В случае кривой Безье имеет еще смысл длина отрезков P1C1 и P2C2. Для моего вопроса это не критично.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В качестве простой альтернативы предлагаю растеризацию.

Промежуточные точки высчитываются очень легко:

```
Point GetMiddlePoint(double alpha)
{
    Point Q0 = Middle(P1, C1, alpha);
    Point Q1 = Middle(C1, C2, alpha);
    Point Q2 = Middle(C2, P2, alpha);
    Point R0 = Middle(Q0, Q1, alpha);
    Point R1 = Middle(Q1, Q2, alpha);
    return Middle(R0, R1, alpha);
}

Point Middle(Point X, Point Y, double alpha) => X + (Y - X) * alpha;
```

Соединив промежуточные точки линиями, уже на 8 точках получаем не такой уж плохой результат:

[image: растеризация не говнокод!]

Comment: Это хороший ответ, но я хочу именно две дуги. Если вы видели, как закодированы символы в шрифтах (точки P идут довольно плотно), то с вашей растеризацией это для небольших размеров символов получается практически попиксельная отрисовка. А это можно просто по формулам Безье сделать, да медленно уж очень. Потом, PHP на дефолт хостингах не умеет рисовать прямые со сглаживанием. Дугами это можно хоть как-то исправить, а тут...

Comment: @AlexanderZonov: У меня практически формулы Безье и есть. Глубину растеризации можно по идее менять в зависимости от текущего разрешения. Ну в общем пусть будет как лёгкий запасной вариант.

Comment: я понял, что вы просто по Безье считаете. Это хороший ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Вы сформулировали задачу так, что она не имеет решения в общем случае.

> Так вот, мне нужно найти такие значения радиусов R₁ и R₂, чтобы обе
>   окружности пересекались с серым перпендикуляром в одной точке, кроме
>   того, имели в этой точке одинаковый угол касательной.

Если 2 окружности пересекаются, то в точке пересечения они имеют одинаковый угол касательной тогда и только тогда, когда точка пересечения одна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примере выше, в первых 2 случаях угол касательной одинаковый, в 3 случае, никак нельзя совместить 2 дуги.

Я нарисовал в редакторе решение для примера, как на ваших рисунках. Решение не учитывает ваше условие про пересечение на перпендикуляре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я продолжу увеличивать радиус большей окружности, и подбирать радиус меньшей, что бы они пересекались в одной точке, эта точка никогда не будет на перпендикуляре. Даже если мы увеличим радиус второй окружности до бесконечности (она станет прямой), пересечение все еще не достигнет перпендикуляра:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение без вложенных окружностей не подходит, потому что дуги не с правильной стороны выходят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоже самое и с решением, когда вторая окружность внутри первой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, так и будет, одна и только одна точка пересечения. Только ее надо найти аналитически. У меня не получилось. Условие на наличие одной точки пересечения вообще не понятно, как формулировать, потому я совпадение касательных просто оформил как пропорцию центров окружностей с точкой пересечения - лежат на одной прямой (там в вопросе есть).

Comment: Я вам показал "на пальцах" что задача не имеет решения.

Comment: что значит не имеет решения? Две окружности, проходящие через определенные **разные** точки, манипулируя их радиусами, нельзя довести до того, чтобы они проходили еще и через одну и только одну **общую**? У вас же на картинках показано, что можно, а вы пишете, что нельзя.

Comment: В вашем условии сказано, что пересечение должно быть на перпендикуляре. Я показал, что одном случае это невозможно. 2 других варианта вам не подойдут, потому что результат будет не тот, что нужно. Вы внимательно почитайте, о чем я пишу.

Comment: Девочки, а почему бы не взять какую-то библиотеку от Флеша, где кубические Безье не было и этих библиотек написали как грязи? Я даже припоминаю какие-то туториалы прямо на сайте адоба.

Comment: @Zergatul, понял, это важная поправка, спасибо.

Comment: @bukkojot, тоже идея.

Comment: @Zergatul, хотяяя.... R может быть отрицательным... Нигде нет условия, что оно положительное. Это, конечно, не совсем то, что подразумевалось изначально, да и разрыв получается в самом R от +∞ до -∞, тем не менее, это позволяет двигаться точке пересечения окружности с перпендикуляром сколь угодно далеко от P₀.

Comment: _"Решение без вложенных окружностей не подходит, потому что дуги не с правильной стороны выходят"_ - почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy, если у нас одна контрольная точка C₁ по одну сторону от прямой, задаваемой отрезком P₁P₂, а C₂ - по другую, то только так "восьмерочкой" и остается решать.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, а что плохого в восьмёрке?

Comment: @Qwertiy, меня устраивает.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, ты бы то, как сама кривая Безье по этим точкам выглядит, приложил, а то непонятно, что должно получиться.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот примерно как здесь https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW3fc.png это картинка из вопроса, сделанная не подходящим мне методом (принудительно задается радиус первой окружности)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64368/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexander-zonov).